# Mobx State Tree reference type and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I'm using mobx-state-tree with Typescript in a React application. And, I'm having an issue with Typescript where it complains about the type of the mobx type `types.safeReference`. It looks like the type of `safeReference` in the model definition is different from its type when you use `.create()` to actually create an instance of the model. In my code, `selectedProduct`'s type is converted to `string | number | undefined | null` in `productStore`, but in the model definition is `IStateTreeNode<...> | undefined | null` and that's why I get an error in my root store. How can I fix that?

Here's my Product store:

```
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";

const Product = types.model("Product", {
   id: types.identifier,
   name: types.string
})

const ProductStore = types
  .model("ProductStore", {
    products: types.array(Product),
    selectedProduct: types.safeReference(Product),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
      // actions here
  }));

export const productStore = ProductStore.create({
  products: [],
  selectedProduct: undefined // the type here is different from the type in the actual model
});
```

And, here's my root store:

```
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";
import ProductStore, { productStore } from "./product-store";

const RootStore = types.model('RootStore', {    
  productStore: ProductStore 
})

export const rootStore = RootStore.create({
    productStore: productStore // Here is where I get the typescript error.
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Another way of reproducing this issue is by trying to create a custom reference. The getter will complain about `undefined` not being assignable to type {...}.

```
const ProductByIdReference = types.maybeNull(
  types.reference(Product, {
      get(id: number, parent: Instance<typeof ProductStore>) {
          return parent.products.find(p => p.id === id) || undefined
      },
      set(value: Instance<typeof Product>) {
          return value.id
      }
  })
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an oversight or the intended behaviour, very interesting. Instead of exporting a `ProductStore` singleton, could you not let the `RootStore` create it for you? I.e. `export const rootStore = RootStore.create({ productStore: { products: [], selectedProduct: undefined } });`

Comment: No, it has to be singleton.

Comment: Is this a case where everything works fine and it's just a TS error?  It seems like `RootStore.create` is looking for a raw value rather than a created store.  If you pass it the initial state of `productStore` rather than the store itself then it works fine.  Not sure if this is at all useful but this answer shows a very different way to combine stores: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081439/10431574

Comment: There's a bunch of utility types at play https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/a212858ad6a7a2a694b936339f71c0b3117344e3/packages/mobx-state-tree/src/types/complex-types/model.ts  But the lowest down message in the error chain is that you have an `IMSTArray` https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/a212858ad6a7a2a694b936339f71c0b3117344e3/packages/mobx-state-tree/src/types/complex-types/array.ts#L54 and it expects an actual array.  It complains that `IMSTArray` does not have all of the methods that an array should.

Comment: Thank you @LindaPaiste, and sorry for the delay! I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking when you are trying to use a snapshot where an instance is typically used, you use [`cast`](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#cast). When you are trying to use an instance where a snapshot is typically used, you use [`castToSnapshot`](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#casttosnapshot).

```js
export const rootStore = RootStore.create({
    productStore: castToSnapshot(productStore)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your problem in detail and I wrote a solution, this is how to use `mst` `rootStore` concept correctly, there is no need to create instances of your store or object, just `@inject` it inside component directly:

```
// Product Store
import { types, Instance } from "mobx-state-tree";

const Product = types.model("Product", {
  id: types.identifier,
  name: types.string
})

const Store = types
  .model("ProductStore", {
    products: types.array(Product),
    selectedProduct: types.safeReference(Product),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    // actions here
  }));

type ProductStoreType = typeof Store;
interface ProductStoreTypeInterface extends ProductStoreType {}
export interface ProductStoreInterface extends Instance<ProductStoreTypeInterface> {}
export const ProductStore: ProductStoreTypeInterface = Store;

// Root Store
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree";
import { ProductStore } from "./product-store";

const RootStore = types.model('RootStore', {
  productStore: types.late(() => types.optional(ProductStore, {})),
})

// And now you can create rootStore with empty object
export const rootStore = RootStore.create({});

// Component
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { SettingStoreInterface } from "../settings/SettingStore";
import React from "react";

interface ComponentProps {}

interface InjectedProps extends ComponentProps {
  productStore: ProductStoreInterface;
}

@inject('productStore')
@observer
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps> {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { productStore } = this.props as InjectedProps;
    
    console.log(productStore.products);
  }
}
```

Comment: But, you're not creating the Product Store.

Comment: It would be created when you inject it in your component

Comment: This won't work. The product store has not been created, so it can't be injected.

Comment: I've whole product built this way, you need at least to test, before you write that it doesn't work

Comment: I'll give it a try, but regardless, this solution as is won't work for me, as I'm using react hooks. I need to be able to use the stores using `useContext`.

Comment: I can convert it to work with functional components

Comment: Let me try this. I'll get back to you. Thank you! It may take a couple of days, though.